# how do you decode/remove rich text in asp.net mvc 3 using razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form that uses CKEditor and all works.
I save the text "Description" in my case and all the rich text gets saved.So far so good.

Now in a particular page when retriving the "items" i would like the "description" text without the rich text how do you remove it?

What I have is

```
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.Description)
```

I have tried to look for decode but cannot seem to find it.

How would you do it?

any suggestions
Thanks a lot

EDITED
Example text

What I get

```
<h3 style="color: red;"> <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">This is just an example</span>.<big>This is red.</big></h3> <p> <big>this is normal text</big></p>
```

What I want

```
   This is just an exampleThis is red this is normal text
```

Comment: What rich text? Could you provide an example of what is the value of the `Description` property in the controller action and how do you want it to be displayed in the view. How it is currently displayed if you use `@Html.DisplayFor` and how does this differ from what you expect? Please provide specific examples.

Comment: @Darin thanks for your reply.I have edited the question it shows what I get and what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@Html.Raw(item.Description)
```

By using `@Html.Raw` you assert that you realize all the consequences of not encoding user input. You assert that you realize the risks of XSS attacks, etc... that your site becomes vulnerable to and you assert as well to take great care of filtering this Description field.

Comment: that worked a treat.However how do you "safely" handle a situation where you want a page to display text without those tags?I have an admin page where the user writes comments against a subject with bold bits etc... however when displaying the article i dont want to see those tags. How do people do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add attribute DataType into your Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Html)]  
public string Description{get;set;}
```